# mistakenly removed the active directory roles from the server01 and cannot see the users and computers objects

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, active-directory-group

I have two Active Directory servers, `Server01` and `Server02`, both of them were in the same domain, both run on Windows 2012 Server R2.

Due to some reason, I moved `server01` to another office, and I setup the DNS and DHCP servers, these two works perfectly now and I mistakenly removed the Active Directory roles from `server01` and I reinstalled the Active Directory roles again and but now I cannot see the users and computer objects, I would like to retrieve these objects I removed,

Question:Can I retrieve the users and computers objects by connecting the server01 to server02?

Please I really need help and advise to resolve this issue. Looking forward for your help and advise..

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

For now you need to be realy carefull mate. You still have good and healthy ntds.dit file on your Server02, where is your users and computers still located.

First, you need to ensure what FSMO roles your Server02 have on his back.
ref. http://www.itnotes.eu/?p=220

IF Server02 didn't have some roles you need to seize them!
ref. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816779(v=ws.10).aspx

Then you need to ensure that Server01 fully deleted from Active Directory.
ref.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555846

And after that you can promote your Server01 to Domain Controller again.

Hope this is helps.